# Spring integration - processing files

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We are using spring integration for a scenario where we are reading a file (xml) and using splitter to split the files into several smaller files.

The flow goes like this: file is picked and is split into several small files and these files are processed individually and transformed. While transforming, we perform a validation whether the received file is in correct format or not. If validation is successful we move the file to success folder while in case validation fails it is moved to rejected folder.

We are facing an issue here, when input xml file has two elements, file splits into two sub files and is processed for validation. When first file validation succeeds, original file is moved to success folder whereas when second sub file validation fails, file is not available to be moved to rejected folder.

Can someone please suggest how can we move the file to success or rejected folder after individual sub file validation is success.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your requirements what you would like "to success or rejected": original file or just its part. If you talk about only those splitted parts, you should think about really creating unique files for them. From your concern it sounds like you reuse an original file name which really would cause a behavior you describe.

Comment: the original file needs to be kept for reference - both in case of success and failure, moving of original file to success or rejected folder based upon validation of sub files.

Comment: So, is your requirement to move the original file to one or another folder only when you done with validations for all the parts? Therefore even if one failure, you should move to to the rejected folder. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: So, you probably need to place an `aggregator` after those validation steps to gather all the results. And then you do a search over the result collection to determine if your file should go to `success` or `reject` dir.  Since you do everything in parallel, there is no way determine the state in the middle. So, it is better to wait for all the evaluations and them decide.

Comment: do you have a example that you can point for reference

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question, but you just need to use a basic aggregator after the validation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/splitter-aggregator-reaper. The next endpoint after that aggregator should check the list of results for the error. Nothing more. The standard `splitter` produces a proper correlation details headers - and default aggregator relies on them